# Get rid of [calculated]

Tags: discussion, tags

The [calculated](/questions/tagged/calculated) tag lacks a tag wiki and also sounds not useful.

Comment: Looks like it could be a synonym of [calculated-columns] with a little bit of cleanup.

Comment: [tag:calculated-columns]